# Casting UIViews to custom Views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, casting

So I have a UIScrollView that is populated with a series of MyCustomViews that are subclasses of a standard UIView. In the delegate callback "scrollViewDidScroll I am trying to loop through all the subviews and call a specific function on them but I don't think the typecasting is working. Here is my code below:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    for(UIView *subView in [scrollView subviews){

        MyCustomView *customView = (MyCustomView *)subView;
        [customView myMethod];
    }
}
```

When I call "myMethod" on customView, the program crashes saying an unrecognized selector was sent to instance. I believe that my type-casting is the issue as the method myMethod works in other situations. So how do I remedy this situation?

Comment: It would seem that not every subview of the scrollview is one of your `MyCustomView` objects. You should check each `subView` to see if it is the expected type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

If you do the following, you don't even need to cast your object to `MyCustomView *`. It can be of any type, e.g. UIView.

```
if([subView respondsToSelector:@selector(myMethod)]) {
    [subView performSelector:@selector(myMethod)];
}
```

**Solution 2:**

You can check the object type before doing the cast.

```
if([subView isKindOfClass:[MyCustomView class]]) {
    MyCustomView *customView = (MyCustomView *)subView;
    [customView myMethod];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For "catch" this issue, use

```
if([customView respondsToSelector:@selector(myMethod)]){
    [customView myMethod];
}
```

and with this, the app don't crash.

Also in your for use `for(MyCustomView* customView in [scrollView subviews]){`